# Corrupted images when dynamically loading ImageSource from image resource

Tags: c#, wpf, imagesource

I have a WPF logon screen that I want to load splash images into dynamically. Most of the time the image loads fine, but maybe 1 out of 10 times the image shows corrupted as you see below.

In XAML I have a simple Image control.

```
<Image x:Name="imgLogonSplash" Stretch="None" Width="800" Height="489"/>
```

I was doing this in my viewmodel through binding, but for simplicity right now I have this line in my code behind.

```
imgLogonSplash.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/Company.myapp;component/{splashImagepath}"));
```

SplashImagePath above provides the name of the image to load. The images are .png files in the main assembly and marked as 'Resource'.

I've tried several ways to load the image including this in my viewmodel below. Can anyone shed some light on why this isn't working properly?

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();

string imageUri = $"pack://application:,,,/Company.myapp;component/{splashImagePath}";

image.UriSource = new Uri(imageUri, UriKind.Absolute);

image.EndInit();
return image;
```

[image: corrupted image example]

Comment: Could be a timing thing. If you make whatever sets that source async and whack in a await.task.delay(200); right after setting source, does the problem go away?

Comment: I'll give it a try Andy

Comment: That is what I am doing @Clemens. The top example is my current code. The bottom was an example of other code I've tried that got the same result.

Comment: Is the image loaded more than once? (Check by using breakpoint.) Is the image file in use by some other application - VS or an image editor or a previous hung instance of your application?

Comment: @BentTranberg This is not an image file, but an assembly resource.

Comment: @Clemens, yes, sorry, wasn't thinking straight. Long day.

Answer (score -1):

I would check the resolution of the images you are using(may be size of the image file), if they are very large and the system on which you run this application doesn't have the hardware memory(graphics) to render the image.

try with a simple yet small sized images.

hope this helps.